# Neo4j; Solving role based access through data in relationships

Tags: neo4j, access-control

Does it exist some way of access permissions for every jump/relationship in a graph in neo4j?

Earlier, with another storage solution, I have stored the role of a relationship as a property IN that relationship. It all have worked very well.

Example: A folder with relationships to its stuff states the role of the folder as "owner". Say, then, that you share the folder with someone with a role of "viewer"; The resulting role for the content of the folder becomes "min(viewer,owner,...) => viewer". And so on through the graph.

Is it possible? Is it stupid? Should it be done some other way?

Comment: Do you plan to implement the access control yourself or do you want to leverage Neo4j built-in RBAC? See an example of fine-grained access control with Neo4j here: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/authentication-authorization/access-control/